# Microsoft 365 (Exchange Online), Disable Internal Delivery

Tags: exchange

We are slowly switching towards Microsoft 365, so we going to use Exchange Online in some weeks/month.

- We already syncing our on-premise AD with Azure, everything working fine so far, except we got a odd mail situation going, at this moment i try to convert "special" users to exchange online, for test and trial, while keeping all others connected via old pop/imap solution.
- i get mails via "onmicrosoft.com" delivered to my exchange mail, (e.g. forward from our mail provider (*user@contoso.com (external provider, main mx) -> forward to user@contosocom.onmicrosoft.com -> delivered to mailbox of "user@contoso.com" at exchange online) as a "workaround" to not break all email flow for all users.
- the issue i got is, that i cannot send an email to an coworker, because exchange keeps sending mails to the "exchange" mailboxes instead of using the "correct" way of mail delivery.

**so my question is, can i disable the internal delivery in exchange online to avoid deleting all users from our microsoft 365 account (which also prevent them from using outlook / office / teams).**

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up an internal relay domain in Exchange Online.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/manage-accepted-domains/manage-accepted-domains

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a hybrid mode Exchange? Take a reference at the link here which introduced different scenarios mailflow in hybrid:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/transport-routing

And if you didn't deploy a hybrid, you may need to check if you have manually configured the connectors you need: [Configure mail flow using connectors in Exchange Online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/use-connectors-to-configure-mail-flow/use-connectors-to-configure-mail-flow)